# Prism - Registering a shared service

Tags: service, prism, ioc-container

Sorry for asking such a basic question but I am stucking and trying to find what I could have gotten wrong.

How do I register a service in my shared code (both IService and Service files are in the shared code base)? 
Should I use a singleton or a instance? And what is the code for it because that isn't clear to me. And couldn't find the awnser online, and [here](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Dependency-Service.html) the code for register isn't given.
The service is a database service if that matters.

I tried:

```
        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        //services
        containerRegistry.Register<IDbItemService, DbItemService>();
        Debug.WriteLine("registered app");

    }
```

But when calling putting this code in the constructor of my viewmodel:

```
IDbItemService dbItemService)
```

The app fails with a NSInconsistency error when run on iphone, the error says :
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
, which probably comes because the contructor can't find the service.

EDIT: The constuctor of the service also has a 'service'  for the platform specific code.

Thank you

**Edit2:**
Yes, I see now that I have register that must be because I also tried that function and copied it. I tried both Register and Registersingleton but both still result in my app failing.
Second the service is a shared implementation, I was trying to so that with "(both IService and Service files are in the shared code base)".

Third I don't get any information on the exception I just ran the code and it just stops and gave me this error:

`Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Native stack trace:`

Futhermore I am trying to implement a database following this [github](https://github.com/mackayn/CrudSample) example.  I did some more debugging and the code crashes after this line in the IncidentService located in the shared project from the example: `_platformDb.Connection.CreateTableAsync<Incident>().Wait();`

I am sorry for not clearly stating what the problem is, because honestly I also don't really know. So if you maybe have an example for how to implement a database in xamarin forms just throw it my way.

Comment: You really haven't provided enough information here. First the method you are calling registers a Transient not a Singleton... Second I'm not sure by your explanation is the service something that is an actual Shared implementation in a netstandard library or platform code?  Third you've missed the actual exception that led to no MainPage being set in your application thus the error you've mentioned.

Comment: @DanS. I have updated the question awnsering your concerns.